# Что не так с redirect в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Почему когда я делаю переадресацию из корневой папки на конкретную страницу в `.htaccess`:

```
redirect 301 / http://site/news.php/
```

в адресной строке дублируется название страницы
`http://site/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/news.php/`

И соответственно ничего не открывается. Как исправить?

Comment: Приведите код к нормальному виду(отделите пустыми строками)

Comment: в кавычках укажите попробуйте `Redirect 301 "/" ....`

Comment: Вообще, если это у вас внутренний редирект, на свой же сайт, то целиком адрес (протокол/домен) указывать не надо. и `/` после `.php` вам точно нужен?